# "Sample collection params" vs. "sampleS collection params"

Tags: plural-forms

I'm developing a piece of software which collects some sort of "samples". Which of the following is correct: "sample collection params" (note singular "sample") or "samples collection params" (note plural "samples")? Or maybe both? This has bothered me many times already (with different subjects of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English, when we form a noun phrase by stringing together multiple nouns, the nouns on the left acts as adjectives. For instance "law school entrance examination" is a kind of examination.  The other words modify "examination", and function as adjectives.  Usually, the modifying nouns are singular. Noun phrases like "samples collection" or "diseases control" or "fruits salad" are ungrammatical.

There are exceptions like "data processing", where data is the plural of datum; "datum processing" is not used. "Data" is only formally a plural; it functions as a singular in everyday usage.

The activity of gathering multiple samples is just "sample collection" and its parameters are "sample collection parameters". The activity of obtaining a single sample is also "sample collection".

Comment: Whoa, thank you! The confusion resolved once and for all!

Comment: As you point out, I don't think _datum processing_ would be used anyway, owing to how infrequently _datum_ is used.